# Cakephp 2.4.9 authorization problems

Tags: cakephp, authorization

I have two roles admin and member

Now I want that the member only can edit his records (Participant), but how I could to that?
And the admin can edit all records from Participant.

```
 public function isAuthorized($user){
  if(in_array($this->action, array('edit'))){
          if($user['id'] != $this->Session->read('Auth.Participant.user_id')) {
                       return false;
          }
      } 
       return true; 
}
```

But with my function, nobody can do something with edit:(

Comment: Can you debug and show us the value of `$this->action`, `$user['id']`, `$this->Session->read('Auth.Participant.user_id')` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
   // Admin can access every action
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
      return true;
    }

   if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'member') {
      if(in_array($this->action, array('edit'))){
         if($user['id'] != $this->Session->read('Auth.Participant.user_id')) {
             return false;
         }
         else{
            return true;
         }
      }   
   }

   //Default deny
    return false;
}
```